# ASP.Net Cross-Site Authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a website using Forms Authentication on domain1.com.

I've been asked how a login page can be developed on domain2.com which logs the user into domain1.com and redirects them to the domain1.com homepage (domain2.com has no membership system and is purely an alternative page to log in to domain1.com from).

Is this possible out of the box or would I need to develop a page on domain1.com which authenticates the login request from domain2.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can reuse the auth page. Create a form in domain2.com pointing the auth uri in domain1.com

Citing [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_form_action.asp):

> the possible values of the action
>   attribute are:
>
> - An absolute URL - points to another web site (like
>     action="http://www.example.com/example.htm")
> - A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like
>     action="example.htm")

**UPDATE:**
I'm supposing you want to only get authenticated for the pages of domain1. although you're sending the credentials from the domain2, you're POSTING your data and being redirected to domain1. so the auth cookie will only be valid for such domain (domain1).

Comment: I've set up domain2.com with the same forms auth settings in web.config as in domain1.com.  It seems to work fine locally.  Would there be any issues with the cookie being set on a different domain though?

Comment: @user528573: Yes there would be an issue with the cookie being set on a different domain. It wont work, for security reasons. See my answer on how to get around this.

Comment: Are you sure that the cookies will be shared across different root level domains? According to http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432851.aspx#488128, the cookie set on domain1.com cannot be read on domain2.com

Comment: How did you set the forms auth settings in domain2.com? I understood by your question that 'domain2.com has no membership system and is purely an alternative page to log in to domain1.com from'.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by adding this to the web.config for both sites inside the system.web node.

```
 <machineKey validationKey="21F090935F6E49C2C797F69BBAAD8402ABD2EE0B667A8B44EA7DD4374267A75D7AD972A119482D15A4127461DB1DC347C1A63AE5F1CCFAACFF1B72A7F0A281B"
        decryptionKey="261F793EB53B761503AC445E0CA28DA44AA9B3CF06263B77"
        validation="SHA1"/>
```

This will allow the apps to share authentication data via the cookie on the client's machine.

You will want to generate a private validation and decryption key. This Microsoft page explains how http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312906