# 2 Projects,Login Page

Tags: asp.net

Can 2 projects in one solution share the same login page and web.config
under one solution? I have 2 UIWebProjects, 2class libraries for the Business layer and Data Access Layer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is named Single Sign On - Single Sign Off scenario.
There are many ways to incorporate SSO in asp.net application , however i would recommend to use WIF (windows identity foundation) as it is part of Microsoft stack for SSO which will also allow you to use other means for SSO like SAML2 or AD etc

you will need to implement one identity provider( IdP , STS in WIF terms) web site and two service provider web sites (or you can use one website as both IdP and SP however i would separate it.

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335707.aspx) is an article to begin with, also google WIF and lookup WIF tag on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called single sign on (or cross site authentication). Here are some resources:

[ASP.Net Cross-Site Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339774/asp-net-cross-site-authentication)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CrossDomainSSOModel.aspx

Comment: that is quite good article on SSO in ASP.NET, however now, having WIF stable for quite a while I rather not code such things by hands and use industry standard tools - WIF is used in MS Dynamics and can be used in Sharepoint also, so why not to use it

Answer (score -1):

I dont think so, never done it.

But you can call one login page from both the application and depending upon the call, redirect url to the respective application page.

Comment: That is the idea with SSO, so you must use proven to work patterns and technologies, instead of reinventing the well. I assume that's you someone gave you -1.